# Coma cluster of galaxies

Tags: galaxy-cluster

According to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_Cluster), Coma cluster contains over 1000 galaxies. Is there any upto date catalogue of these galaxies with the following given parameters `(Ra, Dec, z, magnitude, position angle, major diameter, minor diameter)`.

Comment: Which Star catalogues have you looked at so far?

Comment: I am looking at vizier (http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR).